# DEFINE_PER_CPU to define an array of pointers to structures

Tags: c, linux

The following definitions work when using [DEFINE_PER_CPU](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/percpu-defs.h#L115) in the Linux kernel:

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(int, x);
DEFINE_PER_CPU(char[10], c);
DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct foo, f);
```

I now want to define an array of pointers to structures using the same.

Assume the structure is called `struct foo`, and is to be named `bar`. I then tried:

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(struct *foo[100], bar);
```

However, it results in a compilation error. I also tried a couple of other permutations, but am unable to make it work. Can anyone please point out what will work, and why?

I understand that a workaround could be to create a wrapper structure that stores the pointer which can be used by one of the methods above, but I would like to know how to make it work with pointers.

EDIT: Struct foo does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
DEFINE_PER_CPU(__typeof__(struct foo *)[100], bar);
```

References:

[1] [Linux kernel header](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/percpu-defs.h#L89) containing the definition of `DEFINE_PER_CPU`.

[2] [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) of `typeof`.